# Prove this Binomial Identity by Induction

Tags: combinatorics

Prove the following binomial identity by induction

$\sum_{i=1}^n \binom {i+k-1} {k} =\binom {n+k} {k+1}$

What I have:

We will show that the equality is true for $n=1$:
$$\binom {i+k-1} {k}=\binom{k}{k}=\frac{k!}{k!(k-k)!}=0!$$

$$\binom{1+k}{k+1}=\frac{(k+1)!}{(k+1)!(k+1-k-1)!}=0!$$

So the equality holds true for n=1.

Now assume the result is true for all $i\in$ {$1,2,...n$}.

We will show that it is also true for $n+1$:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \binom {i+k-1} {k} =\binom {n+1+k} {k+1}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \binom {i+k-1} {k}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom {n+1+k} {k+1}+\binom {n+1+k-1} {k}=\binom {n+k} {k+1}+\binom {n+k} {k}.$$

From a previous proof (mentioned in my class), we know that $\binom {n} {k}=\binom {n-1} {k-1}+\binom {n-1} {k}$. Therefore,$\binom {n+1+k} {k+1}=\binom {n+k} {k}+\binom {n+k} {k}$, so the equation holds true for $n+1$.

Comment: Is there a question. If it's proof verification you have it right

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to check if it was correct. Thank you!